# Get goal conversion rate by Time on Page by Page group?

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to answer this question:

Does the average time on page A (or more accurately page group A) affect the conversion rate of goal B?

So far in the GUI I have:

A) Created an advanced segment of Time on Page >= 120 ("per hit" option):

http://grab.by/tKOA

B) Modified the segment to also add a filter for Page = regex matching my group:

http://grab.by/tKOU

...But I don't know if this gives me the results I'm after; that is, if they are accurate

I have some other ideas, including assigning the page group as a funnel step and then segmenting by the Time on Page; still waiting on data to come in for that one

Wanting to know if there was a better solution or if I'm on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Drewdavid,

Your approach is quite smart and correct, I would say, however keep in mind that in this context, you are mixing different scopes:

- Time on Page is page-level metric
- Page seen is visit-level dimension

What you would get in your report is the average time on page calculated from all the pages there were seen during visits which met the regex condition set in the filter (that's what segment does, it included all the pages, not just those that you want to filter). I know this can be confusing, but [see this article](http://www.analyticscanvas.com/segments-vs-filters-in-google-analytics/) that gives more examples and goes into greater detail.

**To achieve what you are after, remove the segment filter and simply use the advanced filtering above the report table (and choose exactly the same regex you mentioned in your question).**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but wouldn't a "Page" be a page level metric? Also, I do have my segment set to "per hit" as mentioned; do you know what then the meaning of "per hit" is?

Comment: It is, but this comes out from the segment definition -- if you look at the condition itself, it says "filter visits". So what you get is all the pages that were seen by visitors during their visits that included the particular page set in the filter (not just the page itself, but ALL the other ones as well -- see the linked article which explains this). If you remove it from the filter and simply use advanced filter above the report table ("Page" - "exactly matching" - your regexp), you will get the numbers you need.

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation. Last request I think: is there a report in the GA UI that could give me a page filter and goal conversion information, or do should I create a custom report?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by goal conversion information -- see the reports available in Conversions section, if you are missing, then I am afraid the custom reports is the way to go. Keep in mind, however, that goal is a visit-scope metric, whereas page is a hit-scope dimension, so things might get tricky :) Can you elaborate on what report/numbers you need?

Comment: Looking at your original post, I think the best way to see if time spent on page lead to greater conversions is to use the segmentation tool after all -- only define the sequence that people who saw Page A then finished the conversion Goal B. Look at Page A under Behavior reports -> Site Content and use advanced filter avg. time one page to compare the results (you would have to do this 2 times and write down the numbers, I am afraid). Segments and "avg. time on specific page" do not go so well together.